# R; looking to make a nice grouped barplot (ggplot2) with % on the y axis, categories on the x axis (9 total) and four grouped bars per category

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
x     a       b       c       d       e         
1   0.380   45.200  3.350   0.015   -0.27
2   0.395   19.790  29.770  0.450   -0.22
3   0.235   8.215   41.355  0.190   -0.35
4-1 0.040   14.045  35.775  0.140   -0.55
4-2 0.090   6.725   42.875  0.310   -0.60
4-3 0.000   6.655   43.195  0.150   -0.71
4-4 0.040   11.375  38.370  0.210   -0.85
4-5 0.000   8.170   41.725  0.090   -0.71
5   0.000   1.545   48.610  0.070   -0.40
```

I tried creating a DF to match my arguments:

```
site <- c(rep("-0.27 (site 1)" , 4) , rep("-0.22 (site 2)" , 4) , rep("-0.35 (site 3)" , 4),
      rep("-0.55 (site 4-1)" , 4), rep("-0.60 (site 4-2)" , 4) ,rep("-0.71 (site 4-3)" , 4) 
      ,rep("-0.85 (site 4-4)" , 4) ,rep("-0.71 (site 4-5)" , 4) ,rep("-0.40 (site 5)" , 4)  )

condition <- rep(c("gravier" , "sable_grossier" , "sable_fin", "vase") , 4)

#here I have a,b,c and d, but in my original df I use these names

#I am struggling with creating a vector? DF? that can match my other arguments!

value <- ?????????

ggplot(DF, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=site)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the edit ! Im new here

Comment: Sorry, I'm still struggling with the question: it seems as if x in the table is a site,  should 
 the vector `site` be a dataframe? Can you explain how `value` should be determined ?

Comment: It's unclear how the top table relates to `site` and `condition` and to the `DF` with `value` in your ggplot call. Please explain more.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, this is an example I took from r graphs. Where value = y axis (in the example they use a normal distribution), site = the sites (x) and/or the altimetric level (e) and condition would be the type of sand (a,b,c and d). So I would have 9 groupes on the x axis with each group having 4 bars (a,b,c,d). On the y axis I would have the % (values in the data frame). I tried creating a 36 (9x4) vector for value.  forgot to add:                     
  value =  read.table("num.txt")
DF <- data.frame(niv,condition,value)

Comment: Ok so I figured out how to make the DF:  condition <- rep(c("gravier" , "sable_grossier" , "sable_fin", "vase") , ****9******)

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
niv <- c(rep("-0.27 (site 1)" , 4) , rep("-0.22 (site 2)" , 4) , rep("-0.35 (site 3)" , 4) , rep("-0.55 (site 4-1)" , 4), rep("-0.60 (site 4-2)" , 4) ,rep("-0.71 (site 4-3)" , 4) ,rep("-0.85 (site 4-4)" , 4) ,rep("-0.71 (site 4-5)" , 4) ,rep("-0.40 (site 5)" , 4)  )

condition <- rep(c("gravier" , "sable_grossier" , "sable_fin", "vase") , 9)


value =  read.table("num.txt")

DF <- data.frame(niv,condition,value)

ggplot(DF, aes(fill=condition, y=V1, x=niv)) + 
geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

[The graph output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2dXf.png)